# Firefox always renders first frame when loading <video>

Tags: javascript, firefox, video, html5-video

For a presentation, I have a `<video>` on which I change the `src` following user input. I want the `currentTime` to stay the same (the video files are specially made for that). I am doing:

```
t = document.getElementById("myvideo");
t.src = new_src = "#t=" + t.currentTime;
```

While the new video file is eventually loaded at the desired time code, the very first frame is shown for a brief time (around 100ms), giving a very visible and disturbing artifact...

Doing `t.currentTime = ...;` inside a `loadedmetadata` or `loadeddata` event does not change this behavior.

**How do I force the video to only render when it has seeked to the right frame, not before ?** (i.e., how can I make this change of source as smooth as possible ?)

Comment: Have you tried using `loadeddata` instead of `loadedmetadata`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event

Comment: @Kendaros Yes, and it does not change the behavior. BTW, the frame loaded for this event is the wrong one (even though the correct one is explicitely specified in the url...)

Comment: I might have misunderstood what you're doing exactly, but what about `video.pause()`, change src, and on `loadeddata`, change currentTime, then `video.play()` again? You might also use `poster` attribute to achieve the wanted effect.